# Finding a substring of a string with recursion using only the next Methods of class String : charAt(),substring(),length()

Tags: java, string, recursion

The header if the method should be ONLY (String a, String b), no overloading!

examples :
a = welcome
b = come
output : true.

a = hi
b = hi
output : false.

a = goal
b = gl
output : false.

This is the code I got to write so far, but the problem is that it returns true in the case of : a = "subtring", b = string. because it keeps moving forward until it finds the t and goes until the end and returns true. I'm stuck about thinking how do I return to the original string if I encountered the wrong letter, recursively of course. My code :

```
 public static boolean isSubstring (String s1, String s2){
    //checking if s2 is a substring of s1
 if(s2.length()>=s1.length())
  return false;
 if(s2.length()==0)
  return true;
 if(s1.length()==0)
  return false;
 if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0)){
     return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(1));
}
//if letters are not equal
 return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Interesting problem. Did you begin working on it? What did you find? Do you have any ideas on how to proceed? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Also, the title of your question mentions "class String" but no particular programming language. Are you constrained to a particular language? You can add a tag for that language, for instance `java` if the language is java.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer, rather than adding long clarifying comments ;)

Comment: @Stef yes I did the moment I saw that it is messy in the comments, how do I message people here so they'll get notified that I responded to their comment ^^?

Comment: Users get notified when you post a comment to their post, or when you mention their name with an @ in a comment. For instance I was notified when you wrote @Stef in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your code by using a different recursive call for the two differing conditions `if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0))` and `//if letters are not equal`.

In the case of `//if letters are not equal`, you want to keep searching for a substring starting at the next character, but you don't know yet where the substring will begin. So you can make a recursive call to `isSubstring` exactly like you did.

In the case of `if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0))`, you don't want to search for a substring that could be anywhere in the string: you want to search for a substring that must be at the beginning of the string. So you cannot make a recursive call exactly like you did. Instead, you should call a different function, which looks only for substrings that are at the beginning of the string. Such a substring is usually called a *prefix*.

So, write two different functions, one function `isSubstring` and one function `isPrefix`. The function `isPrefix` is simpler, so write it first. The function `isSubstring` can call the function `isPrefix`.

Comment: Could you maybe help me out with the Prefix function ^^? forgot to mention that everything should be recursive, even other functions

Comment: @Pompa `isPrefix` is like a simplified version of `isSubstring`, so I'm confident you can do it. How do we know that `isPrefix("welcome", "welc")` should return true, but that `isPrefix("welcome", "wekc")` should return false? You advance in the two strings character by character, just like you did for `isSubstring`, and check whether the characters are equal or not.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code:

a) The `s2.length() >= s1.length()` should be really `s2.length() > s1.length()`

b) Next when you find a mismatch , in the next recursion you intend to compare the `s1.substring(1)` with original s2 but at that time your s2 is already sliced at 1. The code will be:

```
    public static boolean isSubstring (String s1, String s2){
        //checking if s2 is a substring of s1
        if(s2.length()>s1.length())
            return false;
        if(s2.length()==0)
            return true;
        if(s1.length()==0)
            return false;
        for ( int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++ ) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
               return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

- **if overloading allowed**:

  ```
    public static boolean isSubstring (String s1, String s2, final String s2copy){
        //checking if s2 is a substring of s1
         if(s2.length()>s1.length())
          return false;
         if(s2.length()==0)
          return true;
         if(s1.length()==0)
          return false;

         if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0)){
             return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(1), s2copy);
        }
        //if letters are not equal
        return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2copy, s2copy);
    }
  ```
- **with equals():**

  ```
    public static boolean isSubstring (String s1, String s2){
        //checking if s2 is a substring of s1
        if(s2.length()>s1.length())
            return false;
        if(s2.length()==0)
            return true;
        if(s1.length()==0)
            return false;
        if(s1.substring(0, s2.length()).equals(s2))
            return true;

        //if letters are not equal
        return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2);
    }
  ```

Comment: Sadly I can't use overloading or equals() :(

Comment: @Pompa in that case all you need to do is compare char by char until you find a mismatch and then recurse. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Stef, this is what I came up with by using Prefix, still not working out for me, trying to locate to issue, tell me if you could locate it ^^, ignore the main method ^^

```
public static boolean isSubstring (String s1, String s2){
    //checking if s2 is a substring of s1
 if(s2.length()>=s1.length())
  return false;
 if(s2.length()==0)
  return true;
 if(s1.length()==0)
  return false;
 if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0)){
     if(isPrefix(s1,s2))
      return true;
     else
      return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2);
}
//if letters are not equal
 return isSubstring(s1.substring(1),s2);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
 String a = "substring";
 String b = "string";
 System.out.println(isSubstring(a,b));
}
private static boolean isPrefix(String s1, String s2){
if(s2.length()>=s1.length())
  return false;
 if(s2.length()==0)
  return true;
 if(s1.length()==0)
  return false;
  
if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0))
 return isPrefix(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(1));
 else
 return false;
}
```

Comment: @Stef nvm, I found out that I had a = in one of the conditions, I made it, thank you! :D,